# Getting event if connected in RxJs WebSocketSubject

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I wonder how can i get the response, if the `WebSocketSubject` is connected?

In the source code (https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/dom/WebSocketSubject.ts) they have a `openObserver` member of type `NextObserver<Event>`

```js
 socket.onopen = (e: Event) => {
      const openObserver = this.openObserver;
      if (openObserver) {
        openObserver.next(e);
      }
      .....
```

How can i connect to it, to get the event, that the socket was opened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `openObserver` parameter accepts [`NextObserver`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/Observer.ts#L1) interface so you can use:

```
let socket = new WebSocketSubject({
  url: 'ws://localhost:8081',
  openObserver: {
    next: value => {
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
});
```

Or you can create your own class that extends `NextObserver` and pass its instance in parameters as `{ ..., openObserver: new MyObserver() }` .

Comment: Thanks! I went with creating new observer that implements Observer interface, since i needed to pass some Redux stuff.